# Shell Script Output Array into New Line

Tags: bash

I have this code

```
#!/bin/bash
PACKAGE_PATH="/var/www"

prompt="Please select:"
options=( $(ls -l $PACKAGE_PATH | grep ^d | awk '{print $9}') )

PS3="$prompt "
select PACKAGE_NAME in "${options[@]}" ; do
    if (( REPLY == 1 + ${#options[@]} )) ; then
        exit

    elif (( REPLY > 0 && REPLY <= ${#options[@]} )) ; then
        # echo  "You picked $PACKAGE_NAME which is file $REPLY"
        break

    else
        echo "Invalid option. Try another one."
    fi
done
```

My goal would be to keep the listings one below the other in new lines instead of all next to each other. Is there a possibility?

Comment: Btw.: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: Please paste your script first at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: What is better? I need a list of all folder (numbered)

Comment: `mapfile -t -d '' options < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0)`?

Comment: Or if you can use zsh instead of bash, `options=( *(/) )`

Comment: @Shawn, ...maybe also `-mindepth 1` so `.` isn't in the output.

Comment: @Koda, what do you mean, "next to each other"? Please [edit] to include a demonstration of how they're rendering "next to each other" as part of the question itself.

Comment: BTW, also see [BashPitfalls #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29) regarding `array=( $(anything) )`.

Comment: @Shawn, one doesn't need zsh to get just the basenames of directories under `/var/www`. `options=( /var/www/*/ ); options=( "${options[@]%/}" ); options=( "${options[@]##*/}" )` works in bash

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Eww, way messier than a single zsh-style expansion with a qualifier to only match a specific file type. (Though I learned you can't use options as a variable name in zsh; it's a special one already).

Comment: @Koda I think I get what you want. `select` displays its options in multiple columns depending on terminal width and the length of the options. You want just one column no matter what?

Comment: @Shawn, ...the above bash code is doing more; your zsh code, afaict, only works if `/var/www` is the current directory; much of the verbosity in my suggestion is to avoid that constraint. It would just be `options=( */ ); options=( "${options[@]%/}" )` otherwise.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Of course the bash code is doing more; zsh [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) mean you don't have to do that work when writing zsh scripts. You can filter on file type, permissions, even on arbitrary code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select` uses the `COLUMNS` variable to calculate how many columns to use when displaying its options (Which it dynamically works out based on `COLUMNS` and the length of the option strings to minimize the number of rows used). This is normally set to the width of the terminal, but you can change it in your script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

package_path="/var/www"
# Populate the options array with just base names of subdirectories of package_path that start with "com."
mapfile -t -d '' options < \
        <(find "$package_path" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "com.*" -printf "%f\0")

# Prevent bash from updating COLUMNS after every non-built-in command.
shopt -u checkwinsize
# And set it to an artificially low value so select displays a single column
saved_columns=$COLUMNS
COLUMNS=1
PS3="Please select: "
select package_name in "${options[@]}" ; do
    if (( REPLY == 1 + ${#options[@]} )) ; then
        exit

    elif (( REPLY > 0 && REPLY <= ${#options[@]} )) ; then
        echo  "You picked $package_name which is file $REPLY"
        break

    else
        echo "Invalid option. Try another one."
    fi
done

# Restore COLUMNS and checkwinsize for the rest of the script (If any)
# If doing this a lot, consider a function
shopt -s checkwinsize
COLUMNS=$saved_columns
```

---

And since I've been going on in comments about `zsh` filename expansion, a version for that shell that doesn't use `find`. It uses a [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) to limit the expanded filenames to just directories, and a [modifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers) to expand to just the base names and not full paths:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

# Normally on by default, but just in case...
setopt bare_glob_qual

package_path="/var/www"

# List just directories in package_path starting with "com."
# Note change of variable name; options is used by zsh
dirs=( "$package_path"/com.*(/:t) )

saved_columns=$COLUMNS
COLUMNS=1
PROMPT3="Please select: "
select package_name in "${dirs[@]}" ; do
    if (( REPLY == 1 + ${#dirs[@]} )) ; then
        exit

    elif (( REPLY > 0 && REPLY <= ${#dirs[@]} )) ; then
        echo  "You picked $package_name which is file $REPLY"
        break

    else
        echo "Invalid option. Try another one."
    fi
done
COLUMNS=$saved_columns
```

Comment: Really Great. Thank you. Two last questions: Do you see a possibility to show only the folder name and not the path? I would also like to show only folders that start with "com. Unfortunately a -name "com.*" did not help.

Comment: @Koda, please show _how_ you're trying to use `-name 'com.*'` in the above code, showing the full `find` command; done correctly, it should work.

Comment: @Koda If using gnu find (and maybe other versions), `-printf "%f\0"` instead of `-print0` will print just the base name, not the full path.